# How do I annotate on an interface in java?

Tags: java, android, interface, annotations

I am trying to create an interface with an annotation, however, when I try to create the annotation I receive `Annotations are not allowed here`. I don't understand why I am receiving this as I am following a tutorial that does the exact same thing and it works in the tutorial. This may seem like a dumb question but I am new to programming & I have tried researching why I am receiving this problem but found nothing that answers my question. So can someone please explain to me why I cannot annotate in my interface?

```
package com.myapp.groceryapp;

import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface APIService {

   @Headers(
          {
                "Content-Type:application/json",
                "Authorization:AAAAwg8PTZg:APA91bEY2M- 
   GHRhnKptu3VuNaRK3daxSdLf1S8p5ltF8wCvQ5ylGFmSXNCeXnTfymzN5VqWpucoYn8T6wq2ffR6i45sFRO2GE7"
          }
 )

   @POST ("fcm/send")
}
```

Comment: You now only have annotations inside the interface. Annotations must always be put above something - for example above a class, or above a method. You cannot have annotations that are not attached to anything, as you seem to be doing here. Check the tutorial again, there is a difference between the tutorial and what you're doing (and if there really is no difference, then the tutorial is wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should annotate functions inside interfaces.
for instance:

```
 @Headers(
          {
                "Content-Type:application/json",
                "Authorization:AAAAwg8PTZg:APA91bEY2M- 
   GHRhnKptu3VuNaRK3daxSdLf1S8p5ltF8wCvQ5ylGFmSXNCeXnTfymzN5VqWpucoYn8T6wq2ffR6i45sFRO2GE7"
          }
 )

   @POST ("fcm/send")
Call<playlist> func(@Body fooParam param);
```